# Which verses in Az Yashir get the special tune?

Tags: torah-reading, beshalach, song-poetry

I hope the title is phrased well.

This week, being *Shabbat Shira*, we read *Az Yashir* ("Song by the sea"). I have been laining this for many years. There are certain verses that are read with a special "Shira tune" while the rest is read using the normal trope tune / mode.

Has someone published a list of which verses should be read with this special tune? I'm unaware of seeing this list somewhere, but I guess this may be around.

Comment: @paquda Yup! That does it and adds a bonus regarding some verses in Bemidbar. Thank you!